# Select value from range based on match

Tags: google-sheets

I've got the following set of data and have setup a another table to the right which holds the cost of each location.

[image: dataset]

The cost column currently I've got `=IF(EXACT(B2,"Home"),D2*17.2,D2*0.09)`, however the cost per kWh can change based on different locations. I want to be able to lookup the cost based on another table which will make things more manageable.

[image: Lookup table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this formula in E2:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$G:$H,2,FALSE)*D2
```

It will take the value in B2, find it in the G column, take the value from the cell right to that match in the H column. This is the Cost per kWh, so it gets multiplied by D2 to arrive at the cost.

The FALSE is needed to require an exact match.

Drag/copy down the formula to the other cells in the E column.

Comment: Thank you :) I was struggling with the VLOOPUP syntax